# High level way to explain programming concepts to my boss

Tags: software-development

My new boss has a little programming knowledge but not much, he is not technology illiterate but I'm looking for a few suggestions on how to explain programming concepts to him at a high level. Maybe like a pluralsight or treehouse course on building your programming vocabulary. Questions like

What is an API and  why should we use one?
What is responsive design?

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic here, as you don't appear to have a problem related to project management. This question might be a better fit for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question does not appear to be about project management within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: 1) Try explaining those topics to a 5-6 year old kid. 2) explain those topics to other friends who do not have much (any) knowledge in the topics.

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded at a conference explaining an autonomous system architecture in compare to PM / business processes.

In general, talking to a stakeholder requires to pick him up (or to catch up). Try to understand his demands and engage them with your explanation.

If you don't know the stakeholders demands (motivation/way of thinking), start with an assumption and ask for feedback, e.g. by applying the active listening technique.

"I assume, it's quite important for you to ... (am I right?). An API works in a similar manner by ..."